# C# Mono/.NET differential CAD software retrievement

Tags: c#, winapi, mono, registry, 32bit-64bit

OK, I will try to do my best, but I think that my English is still too bad when it comes to complex subjects/phrases.

I have to build a class (as for now it's not static) that retrieves the information about the external application (software available on customers PC).

The Linux class was really easy to code, but now I have to implement it on Windows.

Basically I've encountered some difficulties with x64 registry reading from x86 version of my application: you can do it only by using [DllImport("advapi32.dll")].

From the beginning I knew that software retirement is strongly depending on target OS, so I've created 4 classes:

`public abstract ExternalApplications` that defines some basic methods and it is derived by `ExternalApplicationsWin`, `ExternalApplicationsMac` and `ExternalApplicationsUnix`.

Inmy application I create an instance of ExternalApplications and assign it by switching the operating system type:

```
ExternalApplications ex = null;

switch (Environment.OSVersion.Platform)
{
case PlatformID.Win32NT:
   goto default;
case PlatformID.MacOSX:
   _ex = new ExternalApplicationsMac(); break;
case PlatformID.Unix:
   _ex = new ExternalApplicationsUnix(); break;
default:
   _ex = new ExternalApplicationsWin(); break;
}
```

I this way the method call will be dispatched automatically to the right ExternalApplicationsXXX type.

Now by introducing `[DllImport("advapi32.dll")]` I'm obligated to:

- change the class structure (to static extern)
- it will probably brake Mono compilation on Unix/Mac OS X compilation (with
  DllNotFoundException)

There are several options:
(1) I can create 3 parallel projects (.cproj) with the same target assembly name for Linux, Mac and Windows. The projects will contain the same classes and methods so I can reference it inside my application without any problem.

This option sucks, it lacks of automation: everything is done manually.

(2) I can accomplish a preventive "DllImport" code exclusion by using C# directives like

```
#if !MONO
...
#endif
```

I'm sure that there are many other methods like DLLMAP and others.
I think that more experienced programmers will tell me what is the most elegant/reliable solution.

**EDIT 1:**

I've just discovered that x64 registry hive reading from an x86 application is possible, however only in .NET 4.0 and higher (according to my source, still need to test).

```
string registryBranchPath = "SOFTWARE\MySoft";
RegistryKey regKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);
regKey = regKey.OpenSubKey(registryBranchPath);
```

This solves only one part of my question, the other part (regarding the possibility to use DllImport in Windows specific non-static classes) is still to be confirmed / tested.

Comment: Perosnally, if I was doing separate builds, I'd have a single class (or maybe clones with the same name) with the code specified by compile time constants

Comment: I'm sort of confused. The question seems to be about the Registry, which isn't even available on OSX/Linux. Why not use a 'settings' strategy that works on all platforms as much as possisble?

Comment: In my application I have to detect CAD engine installations.
On linux I can read the output of 'which bricscad' command, while in Windows I have to read registry keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Your class doesn't need to be `static`, only the imported external method is marked as such. Also, the imported method should be marked `private`, as nothing except the importing class should call it directly.
2. You don't need any fancy compilation tricks / code splitting, the `DllImport` is not checked until it's actually invoked.

An example from [MSDN documentation for `DllImport`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.aspx):

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Example
{
    // Use DllImport to import the Win32 MessageBox function.
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern int MessageBox(IntPtr hWnd, String text, 
      String caption, uint type);

    public void MessageBox()
    {
        // Call the MessageBox function using platform invoke.
        MessageBox(new IntPtr(0), "Hello World!", "Hello Dialog", 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1 - Can you provide me an example or a link for the first point, please?
2 - It's a great thing! I didn't knew that Invoke is done on runtime, I thought that the compiler tests/probes somehow all these libraries during the compilation.

Comment: OK, now I see. thank you, even if my original question was related to x64 registry reading, your solution is far more interesting for others and me.

Answer (score 0):

So the final solution for me will look like this simplified snippet:

```
public static class UsageClass
{
    private static ExternalApplications _extApps;

    public static void Initialize()
    {
        _extApps = null;

        switch (Environment.OSVersion.Platform)
        {
            case PlatformID.Win32NT:
                goto default;
            case PlatformID.MacOSX:
                _extApps = new ExternalApplicationsMac(); break;
            case PlatformID.Unix:
                _extApps = new ExternalApplicationsUnix(); break;
            default:
                _extApps = new ExternalApplicationsWin(); break;
        }
    }

    internal abstract class ExternalApplications
    {
        public abstract string[] DoSomething();
    }

    internal class ExternalApplicationsWin : ExternalApplications
    {
        public abstract void DoSomething()
        {
            // Windows code
            RegistryKey regKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine,
                (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem) ? RegistryView.Registry64 : RegistryView.Registry32).OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\MySoft");
            ...

        }
    }

    internal class ExternalApplicationsUnix : ExternalApplications
    {
        public abstract void DoSomething()
        {
            // Unix code
        }
    }

    internal class ExternalApplicationsMac : ExternalApplications
    {
        public abstract void DoSomething()
        {
            // Mac code
        }
    }
}
```